# Specify rrd files for Docker install of Graphite

Tags: ubuntu, docker, graphite

This is my first foray in to both Docker & Graphite so I'm not entirely sure if this is a docker issue or a graphite one (I'm guessing Docker.)

I installed Graphite following the docker install instructions with the command

```
docker run -d\
 --name graphite\
 --restart=always\
 -p 80:80\
 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004\
 -p 2023-2024:2023-2024\
 -p 8125:8125/udp\
 -p 8126:8126\
 graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
```

I can access https://localhost:80 and see the general graphite login page but I've got absolutely no idea where to go from here. The [install page](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#docker) shows that things should be stored in `/opt/graphite` however because I'm installing it via Docker there's obviously nothing in my `opt` directory.

Has anyone been able to find a good tutorial or have any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: This is more a system question than programming, maybe try ask on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to copy the rrd files to `/opt/graphite/storage/rrd/` *in your Graphite container*:

```
 docker cp  myrrds/. graphite:/opt/graphite/storage/rrd/myrrds/
```

Apparently this worked at some point in time. Unfortunately it does not work for me today.